# ruby on rails: include blank if more than one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a form, I want to include blank only in case of `Client.count>1`. Is there a **clean way** of doing this?

Now I'm using this select:

```
= f.select :client_id, Client.all.map{|c| [c.full_name, c.id]}, {include_blank: true}
```

Comment: It is redudant to include tags in your title.You should remove "Ruby on rails: ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tiny decorator:

```
class ClientDecorator
  def self.form_select_choices
    Client.pluck(:full_name, :id)
  end

  def self.form_select_include_blank?
    { include_blank: Client.count.positive? }
  end
end
```

So, in your view you call those class methods:

```
<%= form.select :client_id, ClientDecorator.form_select_choices, ClientDecorator.form_select_include_blank? %>
```

Now you can test that and leave the database interaction far from the views.